# getWriter.println() или .html?

Tags: java, html, servlet

Необходимо вывести статическую информацию в браузер. Допустим, html код будет меньше 10 строк. Какая практика будет лучшей - написания в servlet getWriter.println("...") или создать html файл и подсоединить его к servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Если файл статичный, то можете и `html` отправлять.

Если же вы туда хотите что-то положить и отправить пользователю, то лучше `jsp+jstl`